# Gradle: set env variable for static method on evaluation stage

Tags: gradle, environment-variables, static-methods, testcontainers

In my `build.gradle` script I have a **static method**:

```groovy
static def startDbContainer() {
    var postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer(
            DockerImageName.parse("registry/testcontainers/postgres:11.2-alpine")
                    .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("postgres"))
    postgres.withInitScript("init.sql")
    postgres.start()
    return postgres
}

def postgres = startDbContainer()
```

On evaluation stage I drop to this point:

(in class `org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory`)

```java
    public static String start(DockerClient client) {
        String ryukImage = ImageNameSubstitutor.instance()
            .apply(DockerImageName.parse("testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3"))
            .asCanonicalNameString();
        DockerClientFactory.instance().checkAndPullImage(client, ryukImage);
        ...
```

There's no `ryuk:0.3.3` image in my local repository, so **build fails**.

I can't rise up version of `Testcontainers` for some reasons.

I have an option to set env variable `TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true` to avoid behavior described, because of this branch:

```java
        boolean useRyuk = !Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getenv("TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED"));
        if (useRyuk) {
            log.debug("Ryuk is enabled");
            try {
                //noinspection deprecation
                ryukContainerId = ResourceReaper.start(client);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                cachedClientFailure = e;
                throw e;
            }
            log.info("Ryuk started - will monitor and terminate Testcontainers containers on JVM exit");
        } else {
            log.debug("Ryuk is disabled");
            ryukContainerId = null;
        }
```

So the question is:

**How I can set environment variable in Gradle script before running static method on evaluation stage?**

P.S.: I've read topics here about setting env vars in `test` and `Exec` tasks: it's not my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily set the environment variable from within the already running Gradle process. You need to set the environment variable as part of calling Gradle or inside your environment.

And you can't access Docker Hub to pull `testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3`? Did you consider bringing the image into your registry and configuring it?
See the official docs on how to do this: https://www.testcontainers.org/features/image_name_substitution/#automatically-modifying-docker-hub-image-names